# Is there a way to drag a row from a JQGrid to a droppable textfield using the gridDnD plugin?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-droppable

I would like to drag a row from a JQGrid to a text input field and add a column's text from the dropped row to the end of the text in the input.

Obviously this is a long way from the answer, but dragging a row from a grid with this set up on it (where `#inputTextField` is a 'droppable' text field) results in the JavaScript error `this.p is undefined`:

```
$("#searchResultsGrid").jqGrid('gridDnD',
    {
         connectWith:   '#inputTextField"
    }
);
```

This is because the destination is obviously not a JQGrid and does not have `this.p` defined.  I've tried a few different things...maybe there is a way I can 'trick' the drop event into working?  Thank you so much for any help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out!!  First, make the grid rows draggable (this function should be called in your gridComplete grid event handler):

```
function makeGridRowsDraggable() {

        var $searchResultsGrid  =   $("#searchResultsGrid"),
            $searchResultsRows =    $("#searchResultsContainer .ui-row-ltr");

        $searchResultsRows.css("cursor","move").draggable("destroy").draggable({
            revert:     "false",
            appendTo:   'body',
            cursor:     "move",
            cursorAt:   {
                            top: 10,
                            left: -5
                        },
            helper:     function(event) {

                            //get a hold of the row id
                            var rowId = $(this).attr('id');

                            //use the row id you found to get the column text; by using the getCell method as below, 
                            //the 'unformatter' on that column is called; so, if value was formatted using a
                            //formatter, this method will return the unformatted value 
                            //(as long as you defined an unformatter/using a built-in formatter)
                            var theValue = $searchResultsGrid.jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'desiredValue');

                            //set the data on this to the value to grab when you drop into input box
                            $(this).data('colValue', theValue);

                            return $("<div class='draggedValue ui-widget-header ui-corner-all'>" + theValue+ "</div>");
                        },
            start:      function(event, ui) {
                            //fade the grid
                            $(this).parent().fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
                        },
            stop:       function(event, ui) {
                            $(this).parent().fadeTo(0, 1);
                        }
        });
    }
```

Then, create droppable elements:

```
function createDroppableElements() {

    $("#inputFieldOne, #inputFieldTwo").droppable({
        tolerance:  'pointer',
        hoverClass: 'active',
        activate:   function(event, ui) {
                        $(this).addClass("over");
                    },
        deactivate: function(event, ui) {
                        $(this).removeClass("over");
                    },

        drop:       function(event, ui) {
                        var theValue = ui.draggable.data('colValue');
                        theValue = theValue .replace(/<br>/gi,'; ');
                        console.log("dropped value: " + theValue );  

                        updateText($(this), theValue);
                    }
    });
}
```

Create a helper method to append text to text field (appending a trailing ';'):

```
function updateText(txtTarget, theValue) {

    var currentValue = txtTarget.val().trim();

    if (currentValue.length > 0 
        && currentValue.substr(currentValue.length-1) !== ";") 
        currentValue = currentValue + '; ';

    currentValue += theValue;


    txtTarget.val(currentValue);
}
```